# Upload to Bigquery from python

Tags: python, json, upload, export, google-bigquery

I have a Python script that is downloading data from firebase, manipulating it and then dumping it into a JSON file. I can upload it to BigQuery through the command line, but now I want to put some code into the Python script to have it all done in one.

Here is the code I have so far.

```
import json
from firebase import firebase

firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('<redacted>')
result = firebase.get('/connection_info', None)
id_keys = map(str, result.keys())

#with open('result.json', 'r') as w:
 # connection = json.load(w)

with open("w.json", "w") as outfile:
  for id in id_keys:
    json.dump(result[id], outfile, indent=None)
    outfile.write("\n")
```

Comment: Also, when I was manually uploading the file to BiqQuery from the command line I first had to upload the json to my google cloud. is there a way to automate that to?

Comment: Simply change the format to JSON: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/bigquery/cloud-client/load_data_from_file.py

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To load a JSON file with the `google-cloud-bigquery` Python library, use the [Client.load_table_from_file()](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/reference.html#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.load_table_from_file) method.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()
table_id = 'myproject.mydataset.mytable'

# This example uses JSON, but you can use other formats.
# See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    source_format='NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON'
)

with open(source_file_name, 'rb') as source_file:
    job = bigquery_client.load_table_from_file(
        source_file, table_id, job_config=job_config
    )

job.result()  # Waits for the job to complete.
```

From the code example at: https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery/blob/9d43d2073dc88140ae69e6778551d140430e410d/samples/load_table_file.py#L19-L41

**Edit: the way you upload to a table has change since version 0.28.0 of the Python library. Below is the way to do it in 0.27 and earlier.**

To load a JSON file with the `google-cloud-bigquery` Python library, use the `Table.upload_from_file()` method.

```
bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()
dataset = bigquery_client.dataset('mydataset')
table = dataset.table('mytable')

# Reload the table to get the schema.
table.reload()

with open(source_file_name, 'rb') as source_file:
    # This example uses JSON, but you can use other formats.
    # See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data
    job = table.upload_from_file(
        source_file, source_format='NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON')
```

From the code example at: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/4de1ac3971d3a94060a1af7f478330b9c40cfb09/bigquery/cloud-client/load_data_from_file.py#L34-L50

Comment: Thanks for the report. I've update the links to latest samples and used commit hashes to prevent 404s in the future.

Answer (score 1):

**Update November 2019**

Found an updated [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/python-client-migration) for uploading a JSON to Google BigQuery using Python.

This is my working solution:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

from google.oauth2 import service_account
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

client = bigquery.Client()
filename = '/path/to/file/in/nd-format.json'
dataset_id = 'DatasetName'
table_id = 'TableName'

dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id)
table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id)
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON
job_config.autodetect = True

with open(filename, "rb") as source_file:
    job = client.load_table_from_file(
        source_file,
        table_ref,
        location="europe-west1",  # Must match the destination dataset location.
        job_config=job_config,
    )  # API request

job.result()  # Waits for table load to complete.

print("Loaded {} rows into {}:{}.".format(job.output_rows, dataset_id, table_id))
```